# laravel 5.7, haproxy and ssl

Tags: laravel, https, haproxy

my project works locally (dev) like a charm, but in production, where I did set inside the .env file APP_URL as https://myurl, generated links are in http, so I get the mixed content problem. How to force ssl? App is behind Haproxy, which terminates SSL connection, inside a LXC container. Here's my TrustedProxies middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;

class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $proxies = [
        '*'
    ];

    /**
     * The headers that should be used to detect proxies.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
}
```

any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

File: App/Providers/AppServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
  \URL::forceSchema('https'); // Force HTTPS
}
```

Be sure on your .env files:

APP_URL = "http**s**://"

Last step : File .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```